# Create JNA mapping for C struct with function pointer

Tags: java, c, struct, jna

I am creating JNA mappings to the [OpenMAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMAX) C library. Along the way I am also learning C. I have encountered a struct that I am unsure how to map to, and that I have been unable to find any resources to help.

Here is a snippet from the struct

```
typedef struct OMX_COMPONENTTYPE {    

    OMX_VERSIONTYPE nVersion;

    OMX_ERRORTYPE (*SetParameter)(
                 OMX_HANDLETYPE hComponent, 
                 OMX_INDEXTYPE nIndex,
                 OMX_PTR pComponentParameterStructure);
...
```

"nVersion" is a normal member and is easily mappable in java.

My problem is with the functional pointer SetParameter. (I think that's what it is)

In Java, structs get mapped to a child of the jna.Structure class. Because this is a class (not an interface), I cannot define a method header without a body which is how I have otherwise mapped methods.

Does anyone know what this mapping is supposed to look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JNA uses [Callback](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Callback.html) objects to represent function pointers, and includes [a description of callback usage](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/CallbacksAndClosures.md).

Make an interface that derives from `Callback`, which implements a single method that matches your function pointer's.

```
public class MyStructure extends Structure {    

    public MyCallback callback;

    public interface MyCallback extends Callback {
        void invoke();
    }
}
```

If you read the struct from native memory, you'll get a proxy object you can use to call the function pointer.

From Java code, you can then assign the field a new value like thus:

```
MyStructure s = ...;
s.callback = new MyCallback() {
    public void invoke() {
        // your callback implementation here
    }
};
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for my instance of use. I have come across [this document](https://jna.java.net/nonav/javadoc/overview-summary.html#callbacks) which it looks like you wrote many moons ago. Hopefully you can shed some light on the line "lib.init(funcs);". No other place in this document has "lib" defined and I can't find an init(object) method anywhere in my JNA classes.

Comment: That's just a stub for "call your native library function that initializes your data".  If you call a native function which populates your structure, then the callback field will get set up properly by the time the function returns.